# How to use Flask url_for to deal with '#' or mitigate with a route perhaps?

Tags: python, flask

How do I use a # in the url when using Flask? I am using ViewerJS (for viewing ppt, pdfs, etc)  and its documentation states that its should be used as such.

```html
<iframe src = "/ViewerJS/#../demo/ohm2013.odp" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have tried

```html
<iframe src = "{{ url_for('docs.static', filename='ViewerJS') }}/#..{{ url_for('docs.static', filename='documents/test_ppt.odp') }}" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Keep getting 404. Individually this work as separate url_fors but the # seems to be an issue?

Comment: Yes I see the 404 in the console as well as getting the 404 page